# Apache config file with multiple VirtualHosts

Tags: apache, web-config

I have an Apache config file. It works almost correctly. But there are two problems. First is that there is a ton of duplicate code, that I don't know how to remove, since I am new to Apache. The second problem is with site http://club.ladby.ru/.

It doesn't show the correct site by `VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/club.ladby.ru/public/`.

It continues to open this one: `VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/lovecakes.ru/public/`.

I want to be able to open sites like *.ladby.ru and *.lovecakes.ru besides main sites ladby.ru and lovecakes.ru.

Here is a complete file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAlias www.lovecakes.ru
 UseCanonicalName Off
  VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/lovecakes.ru/public/
  LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all 
  </Directory>
  <Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all 
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all 
  </Directory>
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
  <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride all 
    Options +ExecCGI +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all 
  </Directory>
  LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAlias *.lovecakes.ru
 UseCanonicalName Off
  VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0/public/
  LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all 
  </Directory>
  <Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all 
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all 
  </Directory>
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
  <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride all 
    Options +ExecCGI +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all 
  </Directory>
  LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAlias www.ladby.ru
UseCanonicalName Off
  VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/ladby.ru/public
  LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all 
  </Directory>
  <Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all 
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all 
  </Directory>
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
  <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride all 
    Options +ExecCGI +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all 
  </Directory>
  LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAlias ladby.ru
UseCanonicalName Off
  VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/ladby.ru/public/
  LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all 
  </Directory>
  <Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all 
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all 
  </Directory>
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
  <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride all 
    Options +ExecCGI +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all 
  </Directory>
  LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAlias club.ladby.ru
 UseCanonicalName Off
  VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/club.ladby.ru/public/
  LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all 
  </Directory>
  <Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all 
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all 
  </Directory>
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
  <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride all 
    Options +ExecCGI +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all 
  </Directory>
  LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasterrs.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

[I have solved myself](http://blog.alwawee.com/2014/08/13/apache-config-file-multiple-virtualhosts/) after some experiments:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.lovecakes.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/lovecakes.ru/public/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName galina.lovecakes.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/galina.lovecakes.ru/public/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.ladby.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/ladby.ru/public/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ladby.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/ladby.ru/public/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName club.ladby.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/club.ladby.ru/public/
</VirtualHost>
```

I have removed everything and made it much simpler. It works.